# How can I retrieve a numerical value for the wifi strength on Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, shell, wifi, zsh, macos-monterey

I'm looking for a numerical value that represents the wifi signal strength on my Mac. Is there an easy command line tool that can continuously report wifi signal and/or dropped packet statistics?

Answer (score 0):

So I made a function in z shell to easily find the wifi strength with a numerical value thanks to the help from someone at MoonPoint.com[[1](https://support.moonpoint.com/os/os-x/wireless/wifi-signal-strength)] who knows far more about the utility than I do.

To use it, just append this code to the bottom of `~/.zshrc`. Next time you open the shell, just type in `wifi` to run the command once or `wifi -l` or `wifi --loop` to run it continuously.

```
path+="/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/"
wifi(){
    if [[ -n $1 && (($1 == -l || --loop)) ]]; then
        clear
        while true; do 
            airport -I; 
            echo "Press Ctr+c to exit."; 
            sleep 1; 
            clear; 
        done 
    else
        airport -I;
        echo "\nPass -l or --loop for continous measurement"
    fi
}
```

The output will look like this.

```
wifi
     agrCtlRSSI: -76
     agrExtRSSI: 0
    agrCtlNoise: -94
    agrExtNoise: 0
          state: running
        op mode: station 
     lastTxRate: 130
        maxRate: 217
lastAssocStatus: 0
    802.11 auth: open
      link auth: wpa2-psk
          BSSID:
           SSID: ATTUYrDBxi
            MCS: 1
  guardInterval: 800
            NSS: 2
        channel: 60,80

Pass -l or --loop for continous measurement
```

`agrCtlRSSI` represents the signal strength and can be a value from -100 to 0. The closer it is to 0, the better. I still need to figure out what NIC IC is being used so I understand what power (dB) it translates to, but it's at least better than three little wifi bars when troubleshooting connection speed.

Comment: I did a related answer over here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/66313416/2836621